# how to filter by YEAR of a date (not the published date) in a view

Tags: 7, views

I can add a contextual filter for the YEAR of the published or created date, but not for another date .  How can I create an exposed filter by this other date?

Comment: Are you having issues with contextual or exposed filters, you mention both...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not mistaken this has to do with the granularity setting of the filter. At the moment you add the filter in Views you can set the granularity (if it already exists you can change it by clicking the filter or clicking the settings link behind it).

### Contextual

Make sure to select `Date: Date (node)` as the contextual filter type. Also make sure this is set to `year` to make the filter work per year only and select the field you want to filter on.

[image: Configuration]

this allowed me to use /2015 in my url to filter nodes with a date field with a 2015 value.

### Exposed

If the problem is with exposed filters, just select the date field, and set the granularity to year:

[image: Configuration]

Comment: Also worth noting (I just realized that): you have to enable a date submodule specifically for views integration (module date_views). Without this module, you will not see those granularity options in views.

Comment: I was getting hung up on adding the specific field to the views filter. Instead, the answer is to add the `Date: Date (node)` field as you pointed out. Thanks!